# Need to show how much data (In precentage) filled in mongoDb collection

Tags: mongodb, loopback

I am using MongoDB for storing data in my application. I need to show the user how much data they filled using percentage.

For example:  I have USER collection. In this collection i have several fields. Once the user enter data in their profile. I need to show how much percentage of data they filled in their profile.

In my application. I am using MongoDb and loopback frame work. I didn't defined any property in models.

How to solve this problem.Please help!!

Comment: if you didn't defined any property, on what will you calculate the percentage?

Comment: If we need to calculate percentage We need to define the collection properties in model is it right?

Answer (score 0):

You can add properties in you `user` model and define percentage against that or you can define one object property like the below mentioned

Suppose you have a `User` model and in it is `settings` property, of type `object`

`Settings` object will gave 10 keys. 1 keys is 10% then 10 keys filled is 
100%. So just check whether user have filled the desired setting and mark a percentage.

so your model will be like

```
{
  "name": "Member",
  "base": "User",
  "properties": {
    "email": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "settings": {
      "type": "object"
    }
  }
}
```

and inside your code retrieve the settings object and loop through it to make your percentage

```
Member.findById(your_id, function(err, usr){
    if(!err){
      var percentage_completed = 0;
      Object.keys(usr.settings).map(function(pro){
        if( usr.settings[pro] != "" ){
          percentage_completed+=10;
        }
      })
    }
  })
```

I hope this will serve your purpose.